# ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors No implementation for models.daos.AbstractBaseDAO

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm getting this error in a playframework scala enviroment the classes are already has public please see bellow. Could I also be invoking AbstractBaseDAO directly since it's a trait, this is based in example code from the activator templates. But the error only happens on my code.

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 

1) No implementation for models.daos.AbstractBaseDAO<models.persistence.SlickTables$CategoriesTable, models.entities.Category> was bound. 

while locating models.daos.AbstractBaseDAO<models.persistence.SlickTables$CategoriesTable, models.entities.Category> for parameter 0 at 

controllers.CategoryController.<init>(CategoryController.scala:12) 

while locating controllers.CategoryController for parameter 2 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:35) 

while locating router.Routes while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider while locating play.api.routing.Router for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200) 

while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler for parameter 4 at 
play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:220) at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:220) 

while locating play.api.DefaultApplication 

while locating play.api.Application
```

-- SlickTables.scala ------------

```
package models.persistence

import models.entities.Supplier
import models.entities.Category
import models.entities.Product

import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfig}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

/**
  * The companion object.
  */
object SlickTables extends HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {

  protected lazy val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  abstract class BaseTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  }

  case class SimpleSupplier(name: String, desc: String)

  class SuppliersTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Supplier](tag, "suppliers") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def desc = column[String]("desc")
    def * = (id, name, desc) <> (Supplier.tupled, Supplier.unapply)
  }

  val suppliersTableQ : TableQuery[SuppliersTable] = TableQuery[SuppliersTable]

  class CategoriesTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Category](tag, "categories") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def description = column[String]("description")
    def parent_id = column[Long]("parent_id")

    def * = (id, name, description, parent_id) <> (Category.tupled, Category.unapply)
  }

  val categoriesTableQ : TableQuery[CategoriesTable] = TableQuery[CategoriesTable]


  class ProductsTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Product](tag, "products") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def code = column[String]("code")
    def description = column[String]("description")
    def price = column[Double]("price")
    def keywords = column[String]("keywords")
    def image = column[String]("image")
    def category = column[Long]("category_id")
    def state = column[String]("state")
    def limitsell = column[Int]("limitsell")

    def * = (id, name, code, description, price, keywords, image, category, state, limitsell) <> (Product.tupled, Product.unapply)

  }

  val productsTableQ : TableQuery[ProductsTable] = TableQuery[ProductsTable]

}
```

-- CategoryController.scala -----------------

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import models.daos.{AbstractBaseDAO, BaseDAO}
import models.entities.Category
import models.persistence.SlickTables.CategoriesTable
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, Writes}
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}
/*
  line 12 is after the singleton anotation
*/
@Singleton
class CategoryController @Inject()(categoriesDAO : AbstractBaseDAO[CategoriesTable,Category])(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  implicit val categoryWrites = new Writes[Category] {
    def writes(sup: Category) = Json.obj(
      "id" -> sup.id,
      "name" -> sup.name,
      "description" -> sup.description,
      "parent_id" -> sup.parent_id
    )
  }

  def category(id : Long) = Action.async {
    categoriesDAO.findById(id) map { sup => sup.fold(NoContent)(sup => Ok(Json.toJson(sup))) }
  }

  def list() = Action.async {
    categoriesDAO.getAll() map { cat => Ok(Json.toJson(cat)) }
  }

  def insertCategory = Action.async(parse.json) {
    request => {
      {
        for {
          name <- (request.body \ "name").asOpt[String]
          description <- (request.body \ "description").asOpt[String]
          parent_id <- (request.body \ "parent_id").asOpt[String]
        } yield {
          categoriesDAO.insert(Category(0, name, description, parent_id.toLong)) map { n => Ok("Id of Category Added : " + n) }
        }
      }.getOrElse(Future{BadRequest("Wrong json format")})
    }
  }

}
```

-- BaseDAO.scala -------------------

```
package models.daos

import models.entities.{Supplier, BaseEntity, Category, Product}
import models.persistence.SlickTables
import models.persistence.SlickTables.{SuppliersTable, BaseTable, CategoriesTable, ProductsTable}
import play.api.Play
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfig}
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.{CanBeQueryCondition}
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

trait AbstractBaseDAO[T,A] {
  def insert(row : A): Future[Long]
  def insert(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Seq[Long]]
  def update(row : A): Future[Int]
  def update(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Unit]
  def findById(id : Long): Future[Option[A]]
  def findByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f: (T) => C): Future[Seq[A]]
  def deleteById(id : Long): Future[Int]
  def deleteById(ids : Seq[Long]): Future[Int]
  def deleteByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f:  (T) => C): Future[Int]
  def getAll() : Future[Seq[A]]
}


abstract class BaseDAO[T <: BaseTable[A], A <: BaseEntity]() extends AbstractBaseDAO[T,A] with HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  protected lazy val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  protected val tableQ: TableQuery[T]

  def insert(row : A): Future[Long] ={
    insert(Seq(row)).map(_.head)
  }

  def insert(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Seq[Long]] ={
    db.run(tableQ returning tableQ.map(_.id) ++= rows.filter(_.isValid))
  }

  def update(row : A): Future[Int] = {
    if (row.isValid)
      db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id === row.id).update(row))
    else
      Future{0}
  }

  def update(rows : Seq[A]): Future[Unit] = {
    db.run(DBIO.seq((rows.filter(_.isValid).map(r => tableQ.filter(_.id === r.id).update(r))): _*))
  }

  def findById(id : Long): Future[Option[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
  }

  def findByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f: (T) => C): Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.withFilter(f).result)
  }

  def getAll : Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.result)
  }

  def deleteById(id : Long): Future[Int] = {
    deleteById(Seq(id))
  }

  def deleteById(ids : Seq[Long]): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(tableQ.filter(_.id.inSet(ids)).delete)
  }

  def deleteByFilter[C : CanBeQueryCondition](f:  (T) => C): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(tableQ.withFilter(f).delete)
  }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a *concrete* (class) implementation of `AbstractBaseDAO`. Exactly what the error says. You don't have a Guice module? Or you're going to have a singleton DAO impl?

Comment: That was it, I was missing the entries in Module.scala Module.scala is a Guice thing?

Comment: Yes, that's where you specify which implementation you'll use for your abstract stuff, in a nutshell. If you have time, I recommend official docs: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation